# dynamic css class on a span element - angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I have a span element in ngx datatable. I want to change the css class dynamically based on the value.

Here's my html code:

```
<ngx-datatable #orderinvoice class="bootstrap" [rows]="invoiceSource" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50"
            [rowHeight]="'45'" [scrollbarH]="true" [columnMode]="'force'" [limit]="limit"
            [sorts]="[{prop: 'sNo', dir: 'asc'}]">
            <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of displayColumns" [name]="column.name">
                <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                    <span>{{column.name}}</span>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
                    <span [ngClass]="{'label label-primary': row[column.value] === 'Complete', 'label label-warning':row[column.value] === 'Processing' }"
                    *ngIf="column.name !== 'Actions'">{{row[column.value]}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="column.name === 'Actions'">
                        <button class="btn btn-success mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top"
                            data-controls-modal="custom-modal-2" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static"
                            data-keyboard="false" ngbTooltip="View" (click)="SerachInvoice(row , 'custom-modal-2')">
                            <i class="ft-eye"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Edit"
                        [disabled]="financeYear"   (click)="edit(row)">
                            <i class="ft-edit"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Print"
                            (click)="SerachInvoice(row,'printSection')">
                            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ngx-datatable>
```

in the above i need to apply class based on condition

```
 <span [ngClass]="{'label label-primary': row[column.value] === 'Complete', 'label label-warning': row[column.value] === 'Processing' }"
```

hear class result unable to getting could u please tell me what the cause ??

bellow is the bootstrap classes 
[image]

Comment: _hear class unable to loading_ <- can you please rephrase this and maybe add more details?

Comment: could u see now Alex Biro

Comment: Sorry, probably my problem, but still, I don't understand the word _hear_ in this context. Try maybe copying the error form the console, or screenshoting it.

Comment: And what are the css classes applied to your element? None? Or are they applied and overriden

Comment: can you share your table html code please ?

Comment: can u look into above  pc_coder

Answer (score 1):

Seem to have change from `label` to `badge`

**Docs**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/badge/

**Hack Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3keqr9

Comment: yes its working supun De silva  but all rows  data getting with bold text .. i dont want show like that ...

Comment: Use a class like follows to remove the font-weight
`.fw-default {
  font-weight: inherit !important;
}` **or** .fw-default {
  font-weight: unset !important;
}

new example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2se6yv

Comment: everything perfect .. but the problem is  using that css font style is different from other grid pages .. could u please suggest the same for all pages ..how can i over come this ?

Comment: in the css class set `font-weight: 400 !important;` instead of `font-weight: inherit !important;`

See if that helps

Comment: sorry for interrupting above screens are the diffrece could u please look into that i change css what u said but there is no diffrence ..

Comment: So 'Is Active' not showing a badge ? is that the issue

Comment: No No I'm talking about font size and style Supun De Silva ... Is Active im showing like that only from that grid ..

Comment: to that css class add `font-size: inherit !important;`